# iOS SDK Making webview fade out when loading

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, ios4, uiwebview

Whats the best way to fade out a webview when its loading to make sure people know its loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a custom `UIView` that is a semi-transparent gray color and display it on top of the UIWebView. This UIView's controller should be a delegate to the `UIWebView` so it knows when it is done loading and can then dismiss itself. Edit: this also gives you the advantage of being able to use your own `UIActivityViewIndicator` (spinning wheel) placed wherever you like to be more prominent than the status bar shared one.

Alternatively, you could subclass `UIAlertView` and take out the background image (that blue box) and then `show` this `UIAlertView` while it is loading.

Edit for tutorial link: [Tutorial Link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html) is a tutorial telling you exactly how to do just this (method 1)

Answer (score 5):

You can fade the webview's by altering the alpha in an animation sequence.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
myWebView.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The preferred method of making the user aware of a loading webview is `networkActivityIndicator`.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark WebvView Delegates

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; // to stop it, set this to NO
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO; // to stop it, set this to NO
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO; // to stop it, set this to NO
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could place a view that has a colour of black and 20% opacity over the view in order to dim it (this has the advantage that user interaction with the webview underneath will be disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Why fade it out, why not just use a `UIActivityIndicator`? Or use the shared one? If you really want to fade it out, you can always just create a `UIView`, set the background color to black, with an alpha of say .5. Then just add it overtop of your `UIWebView` while it's loading, remove it when it's done.